# Unable to use local and remote variables within a heredoc or command over SSH

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

Below is an example of a ssh script using a heredoc (the actual script is more complex). Is it possible to use both local and remote variables within an SSH heredoc or command?

`FILE_NAME` is set on the local server to be used on the remote server. `REMOTE_PID` is set when running on the remote server to be used on local server. `FILE_NAME` is recognised in script. `REMOTE_PID` is not set.

If `EOF` is changed to `'EOF'`, then `REMOTE_PID` is set and `FILE_NAME is not. I don't understand why this is?

Is there a way in which both `REMOTE_PID` and `FILE_NAME` can be recognised?

Version 2 of bash being used. The default remote login is cshell, local script is to be bash.

```
FILE_NAME=/example/pdi.dat
ssh user@host bash << EOF
# run script with output...
REMOTE_PID=$(cat $FILE_NAME)
echo $REMOTE_PID
EOF
echo $REMOTE_PID
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the `$` sign if you don't want the variable to be expanded:

```
$ x=abc
$ bash <<EOF
> x=def
> echo $x   # This expands x before sending it to bash. Bash will see only "echo abc"
> echo \$x  # This lets bash perform the expansion. Bash will see "echo $x"
> EOF
abc
def
```

So in your case:

```
ssh user@host bash << EOF
# run script with output...
REMOTE_PID=$(cat $FILE_NAME)
echo \$REMOTE_PID
EOF
```

Or alternatively you can just use a herestring with single quotes:

```
$ x=abc
$ bash <<< '
> x=def
> echo $x  # This will not expand, because we are inside single quotes
> '
def
```

Comment: I think the difference would be clearer if you changed `Y` to also be `X`.

Comment: if echo $X is run after the second EOF, what shall be displayed? Is it possible to set variable within heredoc and use outside?

Comment: @SimonReeves No bash/ssh/whatever program is run in a subshell/forked which is closed when the heredoc completes.

Answer (score 1):

```
remote_user_name=user
instance_ip=127.0.0.1
external=$(ls /home/)

ssh -T -i ${private_key}  -l ${remote_user_name} ${instance_ip} << END
  internal=\$(ls /home/)
  echo "\${internal}"
  echo "${external}"
END
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25744744)