# Error on Stat command with condition statements << directory not found

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to use the stat command to check if a permission is correct on a directory and if not then change that permission on that file. I have done this multiple times but I keep getting "stat:cannot statx '/usr/share/nginx': No such file or directory found. But the directory is there I checked multiple times

```
#!/bin/bash


test_host=(host)


path=/usr/share/nginx


for my_hosts in "${test_host}"
do

    ssh -q -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" root@${my_hosts} <<EOF
        if [ ! $(stat -c "%a" "$path") == "664" ]
        then
            
            chmod -R 664 ${path}
            
        else
            
            echo "permissions were already changed"
            
        fi
        
EOF
done
```

Comment: Please paste your script into https://www.shellcheck.net/ first and fix the four recommendations it makes. That might fix your problem. If not, update the question with the improved script and indicate what still doesn't work.

Comment: Since it's not escaped, the `$(stat ...)` is being expanded on the local system rather than the remote one -- that is, it's looking for /usr/share/nginx on *your* system, not the remote host. You need to escape the `$`. See ["Unable to use local and remote variables within a heredoc or command over SSH"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43483464/unable-to-use-local-and-remote-variables-within-a-heredoc-or-command-over-ssh) (it's about variables, but command substitutions work the same way).

Comment: You might also want to add the "#!/bin/bash" at the start of your appended script to make sure you are forcing interpretation by a specific shell.